# Visual Studio Code cannot find module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Visual Studio Code to work with python code.

But when I try to split up my python code into multiple files I get errors.

The code

`sys.path.insert(0, 'lib/')
from Start import Load_MyProg`

works fine in IDLE

But VS Code flips these lines

```
from Start import Load_MyProg
sys.path.insert(0, 'lib/')
```

and then throws a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Start'
error

I can't seem to get VS to stop moving code around.
It forces the order no matter what I try.
I'm not even sure if this is the reason for the error.

The same code works in IDLE with no issues.
I will try to work with IDLE until I figure it out but I like VS Code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two issues mixed in this question. Let us get rid of the easy one first.

**1. The `ModuleNotFoundError`** is raised if you append the path where the imported module resides to the `sys.path` after it is imported. Hence, Python cannot find the module, as it is not (yet) in `sys.path`.

The other issue is about vscode swapping these two lines. That's because of auto-format on save.

**2. Swapping the `import` statement and the call to `sys.path.insert()`** can be avoided by disabling auto-format on save. Go into the settings of vscode and search for "format on save". Disable the corresponding option.

In general, you might be better off looking into Python's import system to understand how to structure your project such that you don't need to mess around with `sys.path` ;) maybe check out the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).